# Proxy not working in Rails 5 API/React project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, proxy, create-react-app

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bruno_boehm/reactjs-ruby-on-rails-api-heroku-app-2645c93f0814) on building a Rails 5 API with a React front end using the Create React App. Almost immediately I ran into an issue getting the proxy working and after reading every response to this issue I still can't get rid of the CORS error.

So the tutorial must have been written before CRA2 was released as it suggests adding the following to your `package.json`:

```
"proxy": {
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3001"
  }
},
```

If I do then I get the following error when attempting to run `npm start`:

```
When specified, "proxy" in package.json must be a string.
Instead, the type of "proxy" was "object".
Either remove "proxy" from package.json, or make it a string.
```

This led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605997/when-specified-proxy-in-package-json-must-be-a-string), which essentially recommends installing `http-proxy-middleware`, removing the proxy entry from `package.json`, and adding the following to a new file called `setupProxy.js`:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }));
};
```

In my case I used the port `3001` instead, as per the tutorial.

This advice is repeated both in the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually) and in their [v2 Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5103).

They also say that if you don't require advanced setup then you can just use a proxy entry in `package.json` and just use a string rather than an object.

Anyway, I've tried every variation of this to no avail. I'm using axios to make the request, here is the whole component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class ListsContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            lists: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/lists.json')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({
                lists: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Lists-container">
                Lists
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ListsContainer;
```

No matter what I do I always get the same error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/lists.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I assume I could use `rack-cors` to allow CORS but my understanding is that proxy is supposed to make it unnecessary.

Am I missing something super obvious?