# Proxy inside package.json must be a string react issue

Tags: reactjs, package.json

When I run npm start it throws this error:

Proxy inside package.json must be a string react issue

Here is how it looks inside package.json:

```
"private": true,
  "proxy": {
    "api/v1/*": {
      "target": "localhost:4444"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {...
```

How can this be fixed? What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605997/when-specified-proxy-in-package-json-must-be-a-string

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
'http://' 
 "proxy": {
    "api/v1/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4444"
    }
  },
```

to your pacakge.json file

Answer (score 1):

The support of specifying the different paths in the package.json was dropped in create-react-app v2. To also support this functionality, you have to use a setupProxy.js.

For more information checkout the documentation here:

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually