# Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:3000/api/register in register form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, proxy

I am trying to create a register form using React on the frontend, and Express with MongoDB atlas on the backend using typescript everywhere. When I click the submit button, nothing happens, but when I post the request using Postman application I get the following output after a long delay:

```
"Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:3000/api/register?email=test123@gmail.com&password=test123"
```

And I get an empty record in my database, something like that:

```
_id: Object("5d7679d8fa74d54ebb0534b9")
__v: 0
```

Also after long delay i see this error in terminal in vscode:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/register?email=test123@gmail.com&password=test123 from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/ (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I created React frontend using "create-react-app", and already did the following instructions in post: [When specified, "proxy" in package.json must be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605997/when-specified-proxy-in-package-json-must-be-a-string) .

The thing is that I also have a contact form that is working and a proxy is working there, and I get the email when clicking submit in a contact form.

I show my package.json in my main folder (which I use to run my frontend and backend concurrently) in which I have two folders: backend (in which I have dist folder to which I transpile my .ts files to .js), and frontend folder.

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce-template-mern",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p backend/.",
    "backend": "nodemon backend/dist/main.js",
    "frontend": "cd frontend && npm run start",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run backend\" \"npm run frontend\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "tsc-watch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.20.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.2"
  }
}
```

And package.json in frontend folder in which I have a proxy.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.18",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.20.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "typescript": "3.5.3",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.3",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.5",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^8.0.4",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.18",
    "@types/yup": "^0.26.23",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.42"
  }
}
```

Below is my code that should put data in my MongoDB atlas:

```
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + "/../.env" });

const app: Application = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const dbURI: any = process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION;

mongoose
  .connect(dbURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema({ email: String, password: String });

interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const User = mongoose.model<IUser>("User", UserSchema);

app.post("/api/register", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  newUser.save().then(() => console.log("New user in database!"));
});

const PORT = 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Above code outputs "New user in database!", but as I wrote on top of post I get an error, and "empty" object in a database.

Also, another thing to note is that when I run this code below:

```
const newUser2 = new User({
  email: "test@gmail.com",
  password: "123"
});
newUser2.save().then(() => console.log("New user in database!"));
```

I get the desired data record in MongoDB.

I also attach my register form in React below (almost same contact form works when sending mail, so I don't think there is problem with it):

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Field, Form, FormikProps, withFormik } from "formik";
import React from "react";
import * as Yup from "yup";

interface FormValues {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

interface MyFormProps {
  initialEmail?: string;
  initialPassword?: string;
}

class RegisterForm extends React.PureComponent<FormikProps<FormValues>> {
  render() {
    const { values, touched, errors, isSubmitting } = this.props;
    return (
      <Form>
        <Field
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="email"
          value={values.email}
        />
        {touched.email && errors.email && <div>{errors.email}</div>}
        <Field
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={values.password}
        />
        {touched.password && errors.password && <div>{errors.password}</div>}
        <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const FormikRegisterForm = withFormik<MyFormProps, FormValues>({
  mapPropsToValues: props => {
    return {
      email: props.initialEmail || "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    login: Yup.string()
      .email("email is not valid")
      .required("email is required"),
    password: Yup.string().required("password is required")
  }),
  handleSubmit(values) {
    const { email, password } = values;
    axios
      .post("/api/register", {
        email,
        password
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
})(RegisterForm);

export default FormikRegisterForm;
```

What can I change to get the desired result it database after clicking submit button in register form? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Post type API. 
You should send email & password inside the body.
So in code, you will access them by using **req.body.email** & **req.body.password**

localhost:3000/api/register?email=test123@gmail.com&password=test123"

If you sending like this then you should access email and password
**req.query.email**
**req.query.password**

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. Now when I use Postman with POST method and req.query I get data record like this in a database: _id: Object("5d7679d8fa74d54ebb0534b9") email: "test123@gmail.com"
password: "test123"
__v: 0. Still though when I press "submit" nothing happens, and it works only via Postman app. Also when I POST via Postman I get an error: "There was an error connecting to http://localhost:3000/api/register?email=test123@gmail.com&password=test123." There is possibly a problem with proxy too.