# Declared proxy in package.json does not work in all of my projects

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

My backend runs on localhost:5000 and my frontend on localhost:3000. The proxy I declared in package.json suddenly stopped working today. I fetch using axios in frontend like this:

```js
axios.get('/api/posts')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
```

It fetches from localhost:3000 instead of localhost:5000 even though I have included the proxy in package.json:

```json
{ "proxy": "http://localhost:5000" }
```

I've tested on other projects too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67335451/4025157

Comment: @MCNaveen Tried everything on StackOverflow, still not working.

Comment: Looks like http-proxy-middleware could solve your issue. Did you updated the dependencies recently? Do you see any error in the console? Is your backend script running correctly?

Comment: @MCNaveen When using the http-proxy-middleware, my client doesn't open in localhost:3000 anymore.
I use it like this (src/setupProxy.js):
```const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(proxy("/api", { target: "http://localhost:5000/" }));
};
```