# Problem in connecting node js with react js using proxy server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying  to connect react with multiple proxy server
and got this error

error
When specified, "proxy" in package.json must be a string.
Instead, the type of "proxy" was "object".
Either remove "proxy" from package.json, or make it a string.

package.json

```json
{

  "proxy": [
    "http://192.168.29.184:5000",
    "http://192.168.1.5:5000",
    "http://localhost:5000"
  ],

  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

}
```

someone please explain how can I separate it

Comment: This has been asked previously - see [the responses here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605997/when-specified-proxy-in-package-json-must-be-a-string).